# JS - 'function' is not a function exception

Tags: javascript, user-input

I am attempting to get the user input from an  tag and use same in a JS function.

The HTML / JS:

```
<form>
        <label for="guess">Enter a number between 1 and 10</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="guess" value="">
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="guess()">

    </form>
    <p id="answer">ANSWER</p>



function guess(){
        var userGuess = document.getElementById("guess").value;
        var random = Math.ceil(Math.random()*10);
        if (userGuess == random){
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML="Correct!";
        }else{
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML="Incorrect, answer was " + random;
        }
    }
```

I keep getting a runtime error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: guess is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (Week 6 JavaScript Homework.html?guess=:13)
onclick @ Week 6 JavaScript Homework.html?guess=:13
```

This error is thrown on line:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="guess()">
```

I have check the syntax and I cant see what the problem is.
Input  appreciated.

Comment: `id="guess"` is redefining `guess` to be that element instead of the function. Don't use the same name for the function.

Comment: Thanks that was it.

Answer (score 2):

It's part of the [HTML5 spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#named-access-on-the-window-object) to store elements with id `myElementId` as `window.myElementId` (which is also `myElementId` in the global scope). Basically, `guess` was a reference to the element `input#guess`, instead of the function `guess()`.

Renaming either fixes the problem.

```js
function guess() {
  var userGuess = document.getElementById("guessText").value;
  var random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
  if (userGuess == random)
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Correct!";
  else
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Incorrect, answer was " + random;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="guess">Enter a number between 1 and 10</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="guessText" value="">
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="guess()">
</form>
<p id="answer">ANSWER</p>
```